# 13 year old dog not eating, blind with diabetes, vets can find nothing else wrong medically

Tags: dogs, health, senior-pet

I have a 13 year old Collie/Labrador cross who is blind with diabetes. She get's her insulin as instructed by the vet, but in the past few weeks she has been eating less and less, and now barely eats at all.

She seems to sleep most of the time, and has lost interest in walks/treats etc, and generally seems miserable.

When she does eat, half of the time she throws the food back up. We have been to the vet and they say that medically, apart from the diabetes, she is healthy.

Should we be thinking about facing the inevitable or are there maybe other things we could try first that may work? We have tried different types of dog food to no avail.

Thanks

Comment: You've told the vet about her throwing up? What did the vet say?

Comment: I have to be honest, I think old age is playing the biggest role here. At 13 years of age, she's getting pretty elderly, and some of these signs are indicative. Consider that collies and labs average 12-13 years as it is.

Comment: @JohnCavan true, I do know that some diseases (like kidney disease) in cats will cause vomiting and can be treated with antiacids to make the pet more comfortable

Comment: Is the diabetes under control? I assume you're testing her blood sugar in some way (glucose meter or urine dip stick).

Comment: Does she eat steak(raw) if you give her one?

Comment: It's odd that this question has garnered a few responses recently, the dog sadly shortly after this question was asked, thanks for the responses though

Comment: Sorry to hear your dog passed away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If she isn't enjoying life, and isn't curable, letting her go is the kindest thing you can do for her.

Ask the vets what decision they'd make for their own pet and why.